# Communication Between Two Android Applications

Tags: android, notifications

I have two apps, A and B, running on the same device(as I have only one device for testing).

I want A and B to communicate with each other without implementing any backend or service.

App A creates the message (in this case, a notification of an event) and app B receives the message ( also a notification ) in its foreground.

I want to know if its possible to broadcast a notification from app A to app B without writing any NotificationCompat code in app B, i.e the notification appears in app B.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Notifications do not appear in an app. They appear on a device. Beyond that, there are many IPC options in Android. For example, App A could send a broadcast that App B receives via a registered `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, sounds interesting. Can u explain a lil more?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use BroadCastReceiver as well as AIDL[Android Interface definition language] to communicate across the processes

Answer (score 0):

You can display notification from AppA that will have ContentIntent indicating for some activity inside AppB (just make sure that this Activity has exported=true attribute in Manifest). In addition you can send a broadcast from AppB and receive it in some BroadcastReceiver in AppB. The last and in my opinion the least usable option in your case is to use a Binder - but I can't imagine how you can use it in described case. The previous were much more stable. Binder is just another option to talk between applications/processes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into implementing with broadcast receivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast,send message to other application。
and maybe you can use socket to communication with them.